Potential heteroskedasticity in maximum likelihood
I've created a bad loan classifier model using logit regression and maximum likelihood. The actual v expected comparison of the result is shown below. In order to create the chart, we binned the observations in groups of 5% ordered by score. A low score represents lower credit quality and a high score represents high credit quality.
I observe that for the bins with higher scores there is some volatility in the actual v expected. I am concerned about potential heteroskedasticity of the residuals. However, I also think it is normal to observe such volatility as the number of bad loans is expected to be lower on that end, and therefore the standard error of the estimate is higher.
My questions are:

how do I assess if the residuals are actually heteroskedastic?
if the residuals happen to be heteroskedastic, what's the impact on the validity/accuracy of my model?



Regarding your questions, see the answers here. As for solutions: it depends on whether the variance is purely a nuisance parameter, or itself of interest. In the latter case, there's always the option of adding an explicit submodel of the variance, as described in Wilson & Lorenz (2015).
